# JAVA: Splitting a string to get double values

Tags: java, string, split, double

I have multiple strings like [-123.141026905408,49.2636144033057],[-123.141047822927,49.2631]
I want to get double values from it.

```
String s[] = str.split("\\[|,|\\]");
```

I use this to split string but not getting double values. Someone have better solution ?

Comment: Your source data has pairs.  Do you want to preserve this or do you just want a flat list of numbers?

Comment: just want flat numbers

Answer (score 1):

The "newbie friendly" but probably not most elegant way:

1. First remove all [ and ] characters from your input (using [replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to replace them with *nothing*
2. Then split on " "; to receive an array of strings
3. Finally parse those values using [parseDouble()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))

A more sophisticated approach would be to use a regular expression that looks for numbers between [ ] ... and use that to iterate your input. But as said, the above is easier to understand and code down.

EDIT: keep in mind that you actually do not need other people that explain to you how those patterns work. They are nicely documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)! You can find there for example that `[\[\]]` should work nicely to match opening and closing square brackets; by using a *character class*.

Comment: String[] s = str.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").split(",");
It works for me but do you have any better thing ?

Comment: @NomanEllahi Yes, you could split on `split("\\]\\s*,\\s*\\[")`

Comment: not works for me, this expression just returning same single string.